# EOS tokens disappeared

Tags: tokens

I bought 73 eos tokens using metamask a month ago.
I was always able to see the tokens on metamask till today, when they disappeared. I can only see them on the EOS distribution App now.

Comment: Hi I tried to send 1010 EOS to my ledger/MEW wallet, however I can no longer see them there, any Idea how I can find them?
Dave.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23418)

Answer (score 3):

If you could confirm that they're their on http://etherscan.io/address/{your eth address}; then it's there. Metamask sometimes has syncing issues with their backend node...